# jQuery: create new objects... $(object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, new-operator

Can you guys please help me with this jsFiddle?:
http://jsfiddle.net/4CNKa/2/

I am trying to create new (hidden) objects [  **$(object)**  ] on the fly...with jQuery...but so far, I had no luck.
In this jsFiddle it's a div, but I want to be able to create any kind of **$()**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#msg") = '<div id="msg"></div>';
    $("#msg").html('<p id="test">My <em>new</em> text</p>');

    //FOR TESTING         
    alert( $("#msg").text() ); //FOR TESTING ONLY!!!
    $("#msg").appendTo('body'); //FOR TESTING ONLY!!!
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div  = $('<div id="msg"></div>');
    div.html('<p id="test">My <em>new</em> text</p>');

    //FOR TESTING         
    alert( div.text() ); //FOR TESTING ONLY!!!
    div.appendTo('body'); //FOR TESTING ONLY!!!
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4CNKa/3/

Comment: Thanks, but I wanna reference the object as $("#msg") instead of div.something .

Comment: @Omar not sure why you want to do that. because every time you do `$('#msg')` it has to search the dom. later on you can to `$('#msg')` but not when the div was not created yet.

Comment: @Omar - Do you understand what a jQuery selector is?

Comment: I thought $() refers to objects

Comment: I I want to use your example with UI dialog, how will it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new elements in jQuery like this:

```
var el = $("<div class='className' />").html("Hello World!");
el.appendTo($("#container"));
```